# VBA check for empty cells in column and print value

Tags: vba, excel

In column J there are empty rows and rows with a value such as checked.

I have tried to write VBA code that prints "unchecked" where there is an empty cell AND this works, but when it hits a cell with a value (checked) it stops. And it won't go down to the next cell probably because I have formulas in the cell that prints nothing if not fullfilled, but it still contains that formula. In my case I have empty cells until J7 and then it starts again at J15. But this can change from time to time regarding source data.

The reason I want to do it like this is because I have a formula in column J that already have printed some values and then some VBA code that checks for other values in a different column and prints to column J. Column J is the filter master column sort of. So this is the way I have to do it I guess.

My code right now is,

```
Sub DoIfNotEmpty()
    Dim ra As Range, re As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ra = .Range("J:j25")
        For Each re In ra
            If IsEmpty(re.Value) Then
                re.Value = "unchecked"
            End If
        Next re
    End With
End Sub
```

Can I print to empty cells if the cell contains a formula which in this case has an `if` statement that is not filled?

Comment: You have to change `.Range("J:j25")` by `.Range("J1:j25")` but except this problem, I tried your code and it works. Are you sure it's not after the row 25 that the problem exist?

Comment: Ahhaaa i think i figured it out what the problem is. Because i have a formula in the cells i think that excel belives that i have a value in those cells. The reason it works in some is because i have at some point deleted the value in those cells. Do u guys now if there is a workaround to this?

Comment: @DanneL see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except from @Maxime Porté's points out that it should be `.Range("J1:j25")`. I guess the cells only look empty, but they are not.

A cell that contains an empty string, `""`, is not empty anymore, but it looks like it. You can test it like this:

1. In a new worksheet write in A1: `=""` (there is no space in between!)
2. Copy A1 and special paste values in A1. A1 now looks to be empty.
3. Run `Debug.Print IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value)` in VBA and you get a `FALSE`.

The cell A1 is not empty any more, because it contains an empty string.

**What can you do?**

```
Sub DoIfNotEmpty()
    Dim ra As Range, re As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ra = .Range("J1:J25")
        For Each re In ra
            If IsEmpty(re.Value) or re.Value = vbNullString Then
                re.Value = "unchecked"
            End If
        Next re
    End With
End Sub
```

This will mark pseudo empty cells as "unchecked" too. But be aware that it also kills formulas that result in an empty string, `""`.

Comment: Just a little point `"" = vbNullString`, this avoid VBA compiler to create a variable for each `""` and hence improve the performances! ;) @DanneL

Comment: Interestingly, setting a cell's value to `""` will make the cell `Empty` (e.g. `Cells(1,1).Value = "a": Debug.Print IsEmpty(Cells(1,1)):Cells(1,1).Value = "": Debug.Print IsEmpty(Cells(1,1))`)

Comment: @R3uK yes right I updated the answer. YowE3K yes with VBA you don't run into that problem but there is that specialpaste "bug" I sometimes run into.

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit the `Specialcells()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub DoIfNotEmpty()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "unchecked"
End Sub
```

Or, if you have formulas returning blanks, then `AutoFilter()` "blank" cells and write in them

```
Sub DoIfNotEmpty()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheeet1").Range("J1:J25") '<--| reference your range (first row must be a "header")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" '<--| filter its empty cells
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "unchecked" '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers then write "unchecked" in them
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ouh, in some cases it can be faster to run a for/each loop than using autofilter. I tried that some time ago in a quite large Excel sheet and for/each was much faster than autofilter and turn off autofilter afterwards. This might not be an issue in `Range("J1:J25")` but in large data tables.

Comment: @Peh, It's actually the first time I hear about a `For Each Cell In Range` loop being faster than `Autofilter()`, and in my experience it's always been by far quite the opposite...

Comment: I don't have a minimal example to proof what I said. And yes in some cases autofilter is indeed fast, but I had Excel sheets that hit the limit of the 32 bit Excel during calculation (because of ram usage) and we did some calculation time analysis (so my thesis is based on numbers not on a subjective feeling) and so we could improve our calculation time by not using filters by 3 times in some cases.